# How to convert a String to Integer for use in a loop in Velocity?

Tags: java, velocity

The `$pod.id` and `$SplitMap.get("$pod.id")` are not null.

This loop also works:

```
#set($start = 0)
#set($end = 1)
```

But this is not working:

```
#set($start = 0)
#set($end = $Integer.parseInt($SplitMap.get("$pod.id")))
```

It gives Exception:

```
#set($start = 0)
#set($end = $Integer.parseInt("$SplitMap.get("$pod.id"))")
```

Comment: downvoter please give comments if you dont understand leave it.

Comment: does this gives any Exception

Comment: @NPKR thanks for reply it is not giving any exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working
internally for val template takes something which is commented

```
#set($val =1)
//Integer val = new Integer();
#set($start = 0)
#set($end = $val.parseInt($SplitMap.get("$pod.id")))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `parseInt` is that it throws an exception in case the string is not parseable.
In case you have the [NumberTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html) loaded into your context a better solution than `parseInt` is the following:

```
#set($val = 1)
#set($start = 0)
#set($end = $numberTool.toNumber($SplitMap.get("$pod.id")).intValue())
```

Sometimes the NumberTool is also loaded as `$number`.

However, a little drawback is, that the NumberTool simply parses the first number it finds and ignores the rest, so "123a" => 123.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast string `$SplitMap.get("$pod.id")` into `Number` or `int`:

```
#set( $start = 0 )
#set( $spodId = $number.toNumber($SplitMap.get("$pod.id")) )
#set( $end = $spodId )
```

`$number` is the default key name for the [NumberTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html), but it can be override by specifying a different name in the configuration (for example `$numberTool`). You have to check what name for *NumberTool* is used in your Velocity environment.

[toNumber method](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html#toNumber-java.lang.Object-) returns:

> the object as a [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html?is-external=true) or null if no conversion is possible

If you want to have explicite an `int` variable, not a `Number` object, you can use the [`intValue` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue()) on the result. So the second line from above code will looks like this:

```
#set( $spodId = $number.toNumber($SplitMap.get("$pod.id")).intValue() )
```